# How many workspace, readers and writers to use in FME?

Tags: fme-form

I have an Excel dataset, and I want to translate features(rows) to different formats like txt, date, number.

I don't know what is the best practice. Should I create multiple workspaces with multiple readers and writers or one workspace and several readers and writers?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As anew user, please take the [Tour]. Questions with a longer title than body are not likely to stay open.  Please [Edit] your Question to rewrite it, focusing on what you have tried and where you are stuck, then change the title to briefly describe the topic of the Question (as a statement).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few factors (particularly, how much do you want to push the performance), but in general:

- One workspace
- One reader to read the Excel file
- One writer for each format of data you want to write

Just connect each input feature type (sheet) to the relevant output feature type. You can make connections from 1 input to many outputs. It doesn't have to be 1:1.